# How do I update multiple AssemblyInfo.cs files individually with the Albacore assemblyinfo task?

Tags: .net, rake, albacore

I have a solution with a number of projects. I would like to update the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file in each project individually. Most of the info in the files will be the same, but there may be one or two things that I want to be different. I haven't been able to figure out a way to do this with the Albacore `assemblyinfo` task.

The type of syntax I am after would be

```
# I know this won't work but I would like to be able to call the assemblyinfo 
# task a number of times and each time pass in at least the input_filename
task :update_assemblyinfo_files do
  assemblyinfo '/src/myproj1/properties/assemblyinfo.cs'
  assemblyinfo '/src/myproj2/properties/assemblyinfo.cs'
end

assemblyinfo :assemblyinfo do |asm|
  asm.version = version
  asm.input_file = <an-input-parameter>
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea can be to store your common assemblyinfo params somewhere in your rakefile (or in an external file, using yaml for example) that can be read by a method into rake and then configure your task as follows:

```
task :update_assemblyinfo_files => [:update_a, :update_b, :update_c]
```

and then in each update task

```
assemblyinfo :update_a do |asm|
  common_info = get_common_assemblyinfo()
  asm.version = common_info[:version]
  asm.company_name = common_info[:company_name]
  asm.product_name = common_info[:product_name]
  asm.output_file = "your_file_path"
end

def get_common_assemblyinfo()
  #read your yaml here and return it
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This task will iterate through each project in your solution and update each assembly info file. In this example it updates the version (assuming you are using a VERSION file and version_bumper).

```
@solutionpath = "c:/mysolution"

desc "Updates each assembly version"
task :version do |asm|
  FileList["#{@solutionpath}**/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs"].each { |assemblyfile|   
    asm = AssemblyInfo.new()
    asm.use(assemblyfile)
    asm.version = bumper_version.to_s
    asm.file_version = bumper_version.to_s
    asm.execute
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's tackle this one bit at a time. If you have multiple `AssemblyInfo.cs` files, you could create a `FileList` that captures them all.

```
assembly_info_files = FileList['./source/**/AssemblyInfo.cs']
```

And create an `assemblyinfo` task per file dynamically.

```
assembly_info_files.each do |file|
  assemblyinfo file do |asm|
    asm.input_file = file
    asm.version = version
  end
end
```

But, I think you're saying that you might have different parameters *per file*. I recommend you encode as many of those properties statically in the individual files. You'll need some kind of hash of hashes of files => { name => value }.

If you always override the same properties "property_A" and "property_B"

```
assembly_info_properties = {
  './source/ProjectA/AssemblyInfo.cs' => { 
    :copyright => '2011'
    :version => '1.0.0'
  },

  './source/ProjectB/AssemblyInfo.cs' => {
    :copyright => '2012'
    :version => '0.1.0'
  }
}

assembly_info_properties.each do |file,properties|
  assmeblyinfo file do |asm|
    asm.input_file = file
    asm.copyright = properties[:copyright]
    asm.version = properties[:version]
  end
end
```

If you override different sets of properties, use the hash of hashes and use the general `custom_attributes`

```
assembly_info_properties = {
  './source/ProjectA/AssemblyInfo.cs' => { 
    :Copyright => 'Someone Else (c) 2011'
  },

  './source/ProjectB/AssemblyInfo.cs' => {
    :Title => 'Custom Title'
  }
}

assembly_info_properties.each do |file,properties|
  assmeblyinfo file do |asm|
    asm.input_file = file
    asm.custom_attributes properties
  end
end
```